# Listings Character problem

Tags: listings, characters

Hi I want to define a string in Listings but I can not do it in Turkish.

I want to write:

`int[] sayılar= new int[5];'`

but the output is

`int[] saylar= new int[5];`

How can I write Ç,ç,ı,ö,ü,ğ?

Comment: Related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/problem-with-special-characters-in-listings?rq=1

Comment: if @Papiro's link doesn't help, something like is suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116266/listings-in-latex-with-utf-8-or-at-least-german-umlauts) might help.

Comment: @greyshade An answer?

Comment: @Jubobs I'll write one right now.

Answer (score 2):

This should allow typing the characters you requested - basically adding more to the list of `literate`s will allow other characters as well:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{literate=%
    {Ç}{{\c{C}}}1
    {ç}{{\c{c}}}1
    {ı}{{\i}}1
    {ö}{{\"{o}}}1
    {ü}{{\"{u}}}1
    {ğ}{{\u{g}}}1
}

\begin{document}
This is the listing:
\begin{lstlisting}
  int[] sayılar= new int[5];
  also check: Ç,ç,ı,ö,ü,ğ
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: are you sure  about `=\true` ?

Comment: @greyshade Cool. Let's clean up and delete those comments, so.