# Problem with encoding of inserted .m-file

Tags: input-encodings, font-encodings, matlab, overleaf

Sorry for an ugly post, it's my first one & I have very little time.
I have this tiny document on overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{Test.m}
```

where "Test.m" is a Matlab-file saved in encoding ANSI.
What is in this file is:

```
% Żółć  
% Ściąć  
% Źrebię
```

And what I get from overleaf is this:

```
% ????  
% ?ci??   
% ?rebi?
```

Changing encoding of file Test.m to UTF-8 doesn't change antything. Changing encoding of document to cp1250 makes it all worse. Please help.

EDIT: \usepackage{fontspec} made some progress: now I have all desired letters in each line, but the problematic ones go first, than the rest, f.e.: "Źęrebi" instead of "Źrebię".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try with `\usepackage{listingsutf8}`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listingsutf8`:

```
% Just for convenience of a self-contained example
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.m}
% àé
% Żółć
% Ściąć
% Źrebię
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}

\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[inputencoding=utf8/latin2,language=Matlab]{\jobname.m}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Overleaf converts all uploaded text files to UTF-8.)

XeLaTeX seems to be the surest bet here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fontspec}  %% <-- loads Latin Modern

\lstset{extendedchars}
\begingroup
  \catcode0=12 %
  \makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\lst@DefEC{%
    \lst@CCECUse\lst@ProcessLetter
    łżąęć % *** add Unicode characters ***
    ^^00% end marker
  }%
\endgroup

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting{Test.m}
\end{document}
```

`fontspec` will load the Latin Modern family of fonts; it has the glyphs for the accented characters. Or you can use `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont` and `\setmonofont` to load other suitable fonts.

You can switch the engine to XeLaTeX on Overleaf by clicking on the Settings icon (gear icon on the upper right), then select "XeLaTeX" from the "LaTeX engine" drop list.

EDIT: Some accented characters are "swapped" around in the listings output; but they'll be rendered correctly in normal text (i.e. outside the listings). This is explained here: [Problem with special characters in listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/problem-with-special-characters-in-listings)
So you'll have to add some Unicode characters to the `extendedchars` list (code added above).

---

### Alternative: using `minted`

As you can imagine, the above approach can get rather unwieldy. Instead of using `listings` (or `listingsutf8`), you might want to consider using the `minted` package with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\inputminted{matlab}{Test.m}

\end{document}
```

Just bear in mind that if you're compiling this on your own machine, you'll need to run `pdflatex --shell-latex` (or if you're using MikTeX, `--enable-write18`) and have Python installed for `minted` to work.